# What is better 1 Huge Css file or several smaller files

Tags: css, javafx

I wonder if a large css file is better than many small.

I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

On an project we have an css File 132 KB / 4892 lines.

Would it be an performance improvment if i split this file in several smaller css files?

-- edit --
Its the Css for an javafx Application (not an Webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One large CSS file leads to fewer HTTP requests, which can **improve performance**.
>
> Several smaller files leads to **easier organization** which will make development and maintenance cheaper and easier.
>   This is a hard one to answer. Both options have their pros and cons in my opinion.

I personally don't love reading through a single HUGE CSS file, and maintaining it is very difficult. On the other hand, splitting it out causes extra http requests which could potentially slow things down.

**My opinion would be one of two things.**

1) If you know that your CSS will NEVER change once you've built it, I'd build multiple CSS files in the development stage (for readability), and then manually combine them before going live (to reduce http requests)

2) If you know that you're going to change your CSS once in a while, and need to keep it readable, I would build separate files and use code (providing you're using some sort of programming language) to combine them at runtime build time (runtime minification/combination is a resource pig).

With either option I would highly recommend caching on the client side in order to further reduce http requests.

I've settled on using separate files in my design time, and a build process to minify and combine. This way I can have separate (manageable) css while I develop and a proper monolithic minified file at runtime. And I still have my static files and less system overhead because I'm not doing compression/minification at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Http requests will be no problem becouse its an javaFX application and the Css Files are build in the jar (ass a .bss -> binary format of css). I only need to know which one will be readed faster oder rendered farster.

Answer (score 2):

according to your html,if you are using all of your css in more pages then put all of them(CSS) into one file,but if not,you can split to less files.

now it's your decision